# Select rows in pandas dataframe for which value in the column is in XY0001-XY0879 where X and Y can be any digit

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with string ID column that consists of 6 digits. I need to choose only those IDs that end with anything in between 0001 and 0879. First two digits can be anything from 0 to 9. Basically, I need to write something like

```
df = df[df['ID'].isin(values)]
```

but I do not know how to define the list of values.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try something like this:

```
df = df[(df.ID.str[2:].astype(int) >= 1) & (df.ID.str[2:].astype(int) <= 879)]
```

Test:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['XY0001','ZZ1111','AA008','BB0234','ZZ9999','XY0333']})
print(df)

df = df[(df.ID.str[2:].astype(int) >= 1) & (df.ID.str[2:].astype(int) <= 879)]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       ID
0  XY0001
1  ZZ1111
2   AA008
3  BB0234
4  ZZ9999
5  XY0333
       ID
0  XY0001
2   AA008
3  BB0234
5  XY0333
```